# Automatic updating build number before commit to git

Tags: php, git, deployment, version-control

I am using PHP and have a file `version.php` contains the following line:

```
<?php   
      define('VERSION', '1.1.0');
      define('BUILD', 'xxx');
```

I want the git to replace the `xxx` before commit. The `xxx` can be anything unique and not necessary the git hash number.

Since it is PHP script and does not require another compilation process, 
and since the chance of build number is very frequent, I just want to have fully automatic process such that it will be changed everytime when user commit the code.

What is the perferred way to do it?

Comment: props on using git by the way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general way of doing this would be with a [pre-commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 0):

You can think about ["clean" and "smudge" filters](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion)